# Can't make Symfony 2 UniqueEntity work

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I am trying to use UniqueEntity validation in my Entity, but it does not work. I have read for hours and I still did not find a solution. I guess it's something easy to see, but I've never used it before.

When I persist a new Entity/record in database with the same data it breaks to SQL error or if there is no Unique index on the table column, record gets inserted.

Here is my Entity

http://pastebin.com/EwsT5QGy

Any help is welcome because I seem unable to figure it out by myself :?

Comment: You have `* @UniqueEntity("slug")` and `* @UniqueEntity("sha1")`.

Comment: To be more precise you are missing the `ORM`-prefix in your annotation. It should be `@ORM\UniqueEntity("slug")`

Comment: indeed, but when I put the ORM\ in front i get `[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UniqueEntity" in class Repo\RepoBundle\Entity\RepoFile does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.`

Comment: But when you say `When I persist a new Entity/record in database with the same data it breaks to SQL error`. Isn't it the expected behavior??

Comment: @cheesemacfly I believe if you put "unique=true" in column descriptions it's pretty much enough to make unique indexes in database so it throws an error. But this one in Entity description should make it initiate an Form error when inserting. Anyway - not a MySQL error/Doctrine exception.

Comment: You are right. Have you redefined your `findBy()` in `Repo\RepoBundle\Entity\Repository\RepoFileRepository` by any chance?

Comment: not at all, there is only one method that has nothing to do with this case

Comment: Could not find out what's wrong with it.. applied a workaround: just ->findOneBySha1('sha 1 hash here') then check if exists..